# OpenSSH private key deleted every time Azure App Service restarts

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, openssh

My App service needs to communicate over openSSH without password. I have a Linux App Service plan tier B1 hosted on Azure. If I type "ssh-keygen" it creates a .ssh folder in a root and id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in this folder without a problem. So I copy the .pub key to a remote server and paswordless ssh connection works nicely. BUT after I stop and restart App service, this .ssh folder is gone and I need to repeat this process again. Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web App for Container will lose the data when you restart it. You can take a look at the [persistent storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#add-persistent-storage), this will persist the data where you need when you restart the web app. And [mount Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux) is also a choice. You can select one from the two ways.